# Entity Framework how to add automatically generated id of table1 to table2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say we have three tables:

- `Table1` is the principal table
- `Table2` and `Table3` are dependent tables. They have 0..1<--->1 relation with `Table1`
- `Table1.id` is an identity column, automatically generated by the database
- `Table2`, `Table3` do not have an identity column

This will allow me to insert in principal entity `Table1` without dependent. I read that when you make `StoreGeneratedPattern = identity`. EF reads the value generated in the database and stores it in memory cache.

So I want to assign that `Table1_id` to `Table2` which is a dependent table. So my questions are

- How would I get that `id` ? I want to assign that id to table2

  ```
  table2 t2 = new Table2(){ id = ? };   // How?
  ```
- Now coming back, another question is: do I have to assign `virtual` to null in controller?

  ```
  Table1 t1 = new Table1() { table2 = null, table3 = null }    // ???
  ```

**Table1**

```
public partial class table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }

    public virtual table2 table2 { get; set; }
    public virtual table3 table3 { get; set; }
}
```

Another related question: I wanted `Table1` to have either `Table2` or `Table3` related. So how would I connect them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using TransactionScope with Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083796/using-transactionscope-with-entity-framework-6)

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a `Sequence` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077461/how-to-get-next-value-of-sql-server-sequence-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

In the database you have a repeated foreign key to the same table.